# MySQL Using Current_User() as a filter

Tags: mysql

The issue I'm having is fairly simple, yet I can't seem to find a solution.
I simply want to query `mysql.user` and filter the results on `current_user()`.
However, when I use to following query:

```
SELECT *
   FROM mysql.user
   WHERE user = current_user();
```

I get the an  `Empty set (0.00sec)` but I am 100% certain the user exists.

For this example I connect to mysql with user `'root'@'localhost'` which definitely exists in `mysql.user`.

I'm assuming I am using this incorrectly, but I've looked over several posts and various different MySQL, but could not find an answer to this specific issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURRENT_USER()` returns a string in the form `user@host`, while `mysql.user.User` seems to be just the `user` part and `mysql.user.Host` is the `host` part. Maybe you mean:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mysql.user
WHERE CONCAT
  (
    mysql.user.User,
    '@',
    mysql.user.Host
  ) = CURRENT_USER()
```

Comment: Works perfect! thank you so much! I did not know it was possible to select a column like ```mysql.user.User``` and concat it like that. I'm not a MySQL expert at all. Thank you very much!